# PHP PDO insert multiple (10000+) same rows using bindParam. Good practice?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to be able to insert from a form request 10'000 + similar row at once. Currently I've done it with a one row prepared statement looped 10'000 times where I re-bindParam each var.

```
for ($i=0; $i < intval($cloneCount); $i++) 
{
    ... 9 other bindParam
    $insertG->bindParam(':v1', $v1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertG->bindParam(':v2', $v2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $insertG->execute();
}
```

It takes nearly 30 seconds to achieve and is certainly not a good practice. It's 10'000 today but could be 100'000 tomorrow.

If I insert multiples row in one query with `(v1,v2),(v1,v2)...` I need to bind each value to a new param thus I believe I would need to have nearly 100'000 bindedParam in one query. If it's UTF-8 and I count around 2 Bytes (I know it can up to 4) per char my Query will be around 10 to 20 MB and the mysql server is on another machine. Saying this I'm surprised it took only 30 sec for my poorly designed request to succeed.

Is there a way to send only one line and tell the mysql server to replicate the last row 10'000 times?

**EDIT PARTIAL SOLUTION**

Following Bill Karwin and Zsolt Szilagy advices. I managed to get down to 5-6 seconds with the following tweaks for a 10'000 insert to a remote mysql server:

```
$dataBase->beginTransaction();

$insertG = $dataBase->prepare('INSERT INTO G...)
...
10 * bindParam of all kinds

for ($i=0; $i < 10000; ++$i) 
{ 
    $hashKey = sha1(uniqid().$i); //$hashKey is a binded param
    $insertG->execute();
}
$dataBase->commit();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to bindParam() during every iteration of the loop.  The bindParam() causes the variables $v1, $v2, etc. to be bound *by reference*, so all you need to do is change the values of these variables and then re-execute the query.  That could cut down on the overhead.

Also you can avoid calling intval() every time through the loop.  Just make sure $cloneCount is coerced to integer *once*, before the loop.  That's a very minor improvement, but it's good practice.

```
$cloneCount = (int) $cloneCount;

... 9 other bindParam
$insertG->bindParam(':v1', $v1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$insertG->bindParam(':v2', $v2, PDO::PARAM_INT);

for ($i=0; $i < $cloneCount; $i++) 
{
  $v1 = /* something */
  $v2 = /* something */
  $insertG->execute();
}
```

You should also avoid autocommit.  Reduce the transaction overhead of MySQL per statement execution by [starting an explicit transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html), inserting several thousand rows, and then committing the transaction.

But the best way to speed up bulk INSERT of thousands of similar rows to a single table is to use [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) instead of INSERT.  This runs 10-20x faster than INSERT row by row, even if you use parameters, transactions, multi-row insert, and any other trick you can think of.

Even if you have to use PHP to write your data into a .CSV file to disk and then use LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE on that file, it's still much faster.

See also [Speed of INSERT Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html) in the MySQL manual for more tips.

Comment: Moving the count() part out of the loop is far more than a small improvement, as PHP handles count quite slow. Good point! A usual way to do this is for ($i=0, $max = count($array); $i < $max; $i++)

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy, that's true, but the OP wasn't doing count() in the loop, he was doing intval().  Not nearly so costly as count(), but it's still a function call and any little improvement helps if you're going to loop over 100,000 times.

Comment: I know stackoverflow moderators aren't fond of thanks messages but thank you for you answer anyway. It is really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Build a wrapper object for bulk insert.

You want to have something like `$bulkinsert->add($street,$zip);` in your loop.
It should internally build an query string with multiple inserts:

```
  insert into table1 (First,Last) values 
  ("Fred","Smith"),
  ("John","Smith"),
  ("Michael","Smith"),
  ("Robert","Smith")
  ...;
```

I would execute it once after every 100 - 1000 calls of add(). 500 is a good tradeoff between query size and execution time. That way you spare 99.8% of the queries you currently use.

EDIT: 
As suggesten in another answer, move the count() ot of your loop. Additionally, use **`++$i`** instead of `$i++`. (Long story short, $i++ creates a call stack overhead usually to be ignored, but you are in a tight loop where microoptimisations matter.)

Comment: I once asked a compiler developer about the difference between i++ and ++i.  He said by emailing him this question, I had already wasted more computing resources than I would ever save by choosing one incrementation style over another in my entire career.  :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin That depends on what you are doing with it. As I stated, it only makes a difference in **really** tight loops. And I suppose that compiler guy was not mutch into a script language. But you might be right that your comment was not worth the time :-P (no offense ment)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly from your question *Is there a way to send only one line and tell the mysql server **to replicate the last row 10'000 times?*** you need to replicate **the same row** multiple times.

For that, especially if you're doing it regularly, a tally table (with as much rows as you expect to be the limit e.g. 100000) and `CROSS JOIN` may help to do it on db side and with sets rather than loops.

Creating a tally table

```
CREATE TABLE tally(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_populate_tally(IN n INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
    WHILE i <= n DO
        INSERT INTO tally VALUES (NULL);
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL sp_populate_tally(100000);
```

Now to replicate a row 10000 times do

```
INSERT INTO table_name (n1, n2, ...)
SELECT n1, n2, ... 
  FROM
(
  SELECT 1 n1, 'TextValue1' n2, ...
) a CROSS JOIN tally t
 WHERE t.id <= 10000;
```

Here is **[SQLFidlle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70256/1)** demo (**UPDATED**).

Comment: Yes that is also part of the question. I was trying to find the way to do that but I can't actually copy exactly each row.( I thought I could and then modify each row but it wouldn't be efficient).

Comment: @NicolasManzini Please explain the nature of modifications. May be they can be done with SQL.

Comment: I need to insert 10 000 rows with similar content except that each must have a different value for the hashkey colum and the identifier column which is the primary auto-incremented key column.

Comment: @NicolasManzini Please see sqlfiddle that I provided in the answer. auto_incremented field is taken care of. hashkey can be generated with `UPDATE test_name SET hash = SHA1(id);`. Try it. These two statements might be faster then inserting one row at a time.

Comment: I'll try it as soon as I can and set it as the answer if it does the job. Thank you for the SQLFidlle it's very helpful.