# Sensible method to insert multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, insert

I have the following database relationship:

```
|--------|             |-----------------|            |-------|
| Groups | ------- 1.* | GroupMembership | *.1------- | Users |
|--------|             |-----------------|            |-------|
```

I have group ids in Groups, user ids in Users and the both of the in group membership, thus making a relationship between groups and users.

One record in GroupMembership looks like:

```
GroupID | UserID | datetime
```

I have an array posting from a form that looks like this:

```
["members"]=> array(5) { 
                          [0]=> "175" 
                          [1]=> "113" 
                          [2]=> "122" 
                          [3]=> "80" 
                          [4]=> "161"
}
```

Each value (175, 113 etc..) is a user ID. I need to insert a new row into the GroupMembership table for every ID in that array. How does one achieve such a task without kicking the ass out of the database and the servers resources?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Waiting until the last minute to homework, eh?

Comment: Nope, I'm a working man, full time, I call myself a student because I'm self teaching and it's easier to say I'm a student on here than explain that I'm a geek who wants to learn PHP :)

Comment: Even Ansel Adams considered himself a "student" *(of the art)* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I will always be a student of a kind, yes, but when I can rip out top-dollar code I'll probably go by a different title, such as 'no-lifer' or 'expert' :)

Comment: Just saying that even though Mr. Adams was a master at his art/craft (*of photography*), he was a humble man and still considered himself a "student". ;-) Meaning, that he didn't look down at others amidst his fame. Truly, a great man; cheers.

Comment: Very wise, thanks for sharing :)

Comment: You're quite welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four [`INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) statements is not going to kill your server. Here is something you can do:

```
["members"]=> array(5) { 
      [0]=> "175" 
      [1]=> "113" 
      [2]=> "122" 
      [3]=> "80" 
      [4]=> "161"
}

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdbname', $user, $password);
$statement = $db->prepare("
        INSERT INTO GroupMembership(GroupID, UserId) VALUES (
            :__group_id,
            :__user_id
        )
    ");

$statement->bindParam(':__group_id', $DEFAULT_GROUP_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindParam(':__user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
for($i = 0; $i < count($members); $i++) {
    $user_id = $members[$i];
    $DEFAULT_GROUP_ID = <your_group_id>
    $statement->execute();
}
```

mysqli version

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
       INSERT INTO GroupMembership(GroupID, UserId) VALUES (
           ?,
           ?
       )
 ")
for($i = 0; $i < count($members); $i++) {
    $user_id = $members[$i];
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $DEFAULT_GROUP_ID, $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: "4 Insert statement is not going to kill your server." I wasn't going to list the entire array here, there could be up to and over 500 inserts requested regularly to the same database from different SaaS instances. And... WHY PDO haha I haven't looked into PDO yet, can I be very cheeky and ask for a MySQLi version to play around with? Thanks for the PDO example though I can see the login of what you're doing.

Comment: In that case you'll want to look into a FIFO queue. 500 inserts is a lot for anything. I'll do the mysqli version

Comment: Doesn't MySQLi manage FIFO to an extent anyway? Chewing through the inserts executed? Is there a way to do this without looping through INSERT queries or does a 'multiple query' function not actually exist? (I've looked, but couldn't find much)

Comment: Well, PHP is not async, it will block until all the inserts have either failed or succeeded. Regardless of what database abstraction layer you use, it will still block until finished. If this is a large import thing, you should look into `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement

Comment: Taking a look now, I'll definitely tick and up your MySQLi answer, you've been a massive help!

Comment: @RPM You only need to [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) once outside of the loop (unless you were using [`bindValue`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php). Same holds true for `->prepare`. In this situation, I would even suggest a batch insert, such as `INSERT INTO GroupMembership(GroupID, UserID) VALUES (0, 175),(0, 113),(0, ...),...`.

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is quite amazing, I've never heard of this before. And I didn't know this was possible @DaveChen, `INSERT INTO GroupMembership(GroupID, UserID) VALUES (0, 175),(0, 113),(0, ...),...` would solve my problem 100%, but as @RPM stated, my database server may not handle such a demanding query on a bigger scale.

Comment: @Dave Chen Absolutely not. You're right on the first part (prepare only being needed once, and I've edited to reflect that), but each `bindParam` statement is unique. Why would you think you would only need to do that once?

Comment: Thanks again RPM, you have been a massive massive help with your insights! +1

Comment: @Arbiter not a problem.

Comment: @RPM The functions [`bindParam`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) are bound by reference. (Check out the `&` beside the '&$var1`) [They only need to called once.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16887038)

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Nice, I never new that.

Comment: According to your samples above, bindparam only needs to be called once outside of the loop for PDO and it needs to be called again and again within the loop for mysqli? Is that right or can I modify it to use bind param outside of the loop for mysqli too?

Comment: @Arbiter Both functions from Mysqli and PDO behave in the same matter, they bound variables by reference. You may, and it is encouraged to bind variables outside of loops to save time on function overhead.